# Is it possible to edit outlined text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am using the Illustrator CC to create a simple piece that is mostly text.

I outlined the text and now I want to edit the text.  Specifically, I want to change the font but Illustrator will not let me do that.

I'm guessing that once you "create outlines" that you cannot go back and change the text later.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 8):

Once you outline text, it is art, not type. You can not reverse the outline processes other than selecting `Edit > Undo` from the menu (if the file has not been closed and undo is still a possibility).

Comment: Although undo history is optionally saved after closing the program in newer versions of Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

The best (if not the only proper) way to meet your need is to retype text and then use the Appearance panel:

1) Add New Fill – pick the desired color or the one your your text already has (or more advanced things like gradients and patterns, if needed).

2) Add New Stroke – choose color, set weight and then:

3) send this "Stroke" line **behind** your Fill in the Appearance panel (drag the visibility-eye icon). 
This provides that a heavy stroke wouldn't "eat" text characters, because the only possible alingment of a stroke for **editable** text is "center".

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using OCR tools and plugins for Illustrator, such as the one below. By far a better option than rekeying if you’re frequently handling outlined text.
https://www.esko.com/en/products/deskpack/plugins/text-recognition